# Change Header/Background Color For Attribute Popup Window (JavaScript Web AppBuilder)

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder

After creating a web app and downloading it using the JavaScript Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS (Developer Edition), I was able to change the site header and widget popup color schemes via an existing style.css file (themes\FoldableTheme\styles). However, the header/background color for the attribute popup window (for the feature layers) remains the default light blue. Even when toggling between different style schemes, (black, cyan, green, purple) the attribute popup window color remained the same.

Is it possible to change this popup color to match the custom header? If so, where and what file would I alter the code in? I only want to change the blue shown below. The white and text color can remain the same.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried to change the css rule for the titlePane-Class yet?

for example:

```
.esriPopup .titlePane {
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: default;
    line-height: 20px;
    background: green !important;

}
```

Comment: Do you know what file this command would be in? I have searched through the '\jimu.js\css\jimu.css' file and a few others, but haven't located what you have referenced.

Comment: you can just write it on your own inside a style-tag or insert it in the last css-file you include in your html-file